# Matplotlib pyplot: plotting array mixes up y axis labels

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

I'm making a simple program in Python to plot two lists of integers, one data one the time axis.
The time list goes from 0 to 3 in increments of 1, while the data list consists of: 5,10, 3,12. I used print statements to verify that the lists do have the values mentioned above.

```
    plt.plot(time_axis,data_array, 'ro')
    plt.axis([0, 20, 0, 20])
    plt.show()
```

However, as shown in the image, the plot y axis is labeled in the order that my data list is processed, not in ascending order: 5,10,3,12

Is there a way to make the y axis go in equal increasing increments upto 20?

[image]

EDIT: I noticed that this mixup only happens when i use the list as a parameter: eg,

```
plt.plot([0,1,2,3],[5,10,3,12],'bo')  #gives the correct graph while     
plt.plot(time_axis,data_array,'bo')   #gives the incorrect graph,
```

Even though the two lists time_axis and data_array contain the same values.
Tracing back my error, I was importing my data values from a text file, and the parsing was done incorrectly, so the data values were not ints. The char values were in the format '5\n',etc so numplot was getting confused. Fixing that solved the issue!

Comment: try `plt.axis(range(start, end, increment))`?

Comment: Can you print out the `time_axis` and `data_array` for us?

Comment: Can you post the image? When I plot it I get equally spaced increments on the y-axis.

Comment: @Q.Holness That gives me the following error: v must contain [xmin xmax ymin ymax] since plt.axis() needs those 4 parameters.

Comment: Here is the printed output of data:

data: 5
 time: 0  |

data: 10
   time: 1  |

data: 3
   time: 2  |

data: 12
   time: 3

Comment: @abobo Is `data_array` a pipe separated string?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're omitting the code which is making this screwy, but here's what I did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_axis = range(0,4)
data_array=[5,10,3,12]
plt.plot(time_axis,data_array, 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 20, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

This produces the image: [image: Plot from matplotlbi]
which seems to be what you were aiming for.

Comment: Yeah, i think i figured it out. I was importing my data values from a text file, and the parsing was done incorrectly, so the data values were not ints. Fixing that should solve the issue!

Comment: This was already stated by OP. The fact that the graph works with numbers.

Comment: @HarvIpan Yeah, I was collecting my comment into an answer, which I had made before OP edited his question. I also emphasized that OP was omitting the problematic code, not providing enough info.

Comment: Btw, even if you've figured out the problem, I would recommend fixing your question to better reflect the problem you were having. You can then indicate at the end how you solved it. This way it will better help other users who have the same problem, and your question might be better received. Consider that your question was most likely downvoted because you did not give enough information to adequately address the problem. Taking the time to format things nicely and overall make the question cleaner and more readable goes a long way as well.